# Call C# rest service from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

How could I call this type of method from a js ajax call?

Should I make this method in a different way?

what's the URL to call?

```
namespace X.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {


        [Route("signup")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SignUp(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (model == null || !model.IsValid())
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Error("Invalid email and/or password"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the URL to call: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=how+to+call+a+rest+api+from+javascript&spf=1496337926161

Answer (score 1):

The URL would be `api/user/signup` (RoutePrefix + Route) and you need to pass the `LoginModel` properties to it.

You can call it in javascript with jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"api/user/signup",
    type:"POST",
    data:data,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this action with core javacript, your code will look like this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="UserAction()">Search</button>

function PostData()
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "api_url_here", false);  //Method Type
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
}
```

and with JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "api_url",
   type: "POST", //Method Type
   data: DATA//Data to post
});
```